# Updating a field in an object in an array with Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a poll website with Firebase + React and I want to create a function for voting, which means that the vote field of the option should increment by 1 when the user makes a choice.

This is what my document structure looks like in Firestore:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7juCy.png

I have a map function in my return part which can get the index number of the choice (I set it in "selectedChoice"). I can also set the "id" of the document using useParams. But the problem is, since the field I want to update is within an object which is already within an array, I can't reach it with any of the Firestore functions. This was the last code I tried but it creates a new choice and deletes the others, rather than updating.

```
  async function handleVote() {
    const pollRef = doc(db, "polls", id);
    try {
      await updateDoc(pollRef, {
        [`choices.${selectedChoice}.vote`]: increment(1),
      });
      console.log("Document updated");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error updating document: ", error);
    }
  }
```

Can you please help me, how to update the vote field with Firebase? Should I map the choices? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `choices` field inside the document is an array that contains objects. But please note, that there is no way you can update an object within the array using an index. So the following line of code:

```
[`choices.${selectedChoice}.vote`]: increment(1)
```

Won't perform the incrementation. It would have worked if the `choices` field was a map.

In case of the an array, you have to read the document, perform the update in the array in memory, and then write the document back to Firestore.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think changing the document structure is more practical since I am in the beginning of the project. So, how should I restructure my documents so that I can update the vote field of a choice?

Comment: Not necessary. Please also check the link in your question comment,

Comment: Hey cany. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?